# Finding Curvatures of Parabolas

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Use the formula for the center of curvature c of a curve $r=r(t)$ at a arbitrary point r(t) given by $c-r=-\dot r^{3}(\dot r \land \ddot r)^{-1}$ to find the center of curvature of the semicubical parabola $y^{2}=x^{3}$ at the point $( 4,8)$. The position vector of a point on the curve is $r=r(t)$ for some parameter t. On a parabola $y=x^{2}$, $r(x)=(x,x^{2})$. Hence, on a parabola, $r=(xe_1 + x^{2}e_2)$ with r as a function of x and x could be time. Hence, on a parabola, $(\dot r(x) \land \ddot r(x)^{-1})$= $(\frac{1 e_2 e_1}{2})$

Comment: I am trying to use the given information to solve the semicubical parabola

Comment: Also note on a parabola $\dot r(x)=e_1+2xe_2$ is the derivative respect to x

Comment: also note on a parabola $\dot r(x) \land \ddot r(x)= 2e_1 e_2$

Comment: I do not know what to put in front of $e_1  + e_2$ for the semicubical parabola. If I get that then I solve the curvature

Answer (score 0):

Hence, on a parabola $y=x^{2}$, $r=(xe_1+x^{2}e_2)$
 so I'm guessing on a semicubical parabola $y^{2}=x^{3}$, $r=(x^{2}e_1+x^{3}e_2)$ with r as a function of x. 
Based on my guess for the semicubical parabola. $\dot r(x)=2xe_1+3x^{2}e_2$.note: derivative with respect to x
Then $\dot r(x)^{2}=\Vert \dot r(x)\Vert=4x^{2}+9x^{4}$. So $\dot r(x)^{3}= 4x^{2}+9x^{4}(2xe_1+3x^{2}e_2)$
So $\dot r(x) \land \ddot r(x)= (2xe_1+3x^{2}e_2) \land (2e_1+6xe_2)$= $12e_1e_2 +6e_2e_1$=$12e_1e_2-6e_1e_2$=$6e_1e_2$.
 Hence, $(\dot r(x) \land \ddot r(x))^{-1}$= $\frac{1e_2e_1}{6}$
so $r(x)-c=(4x^{2}+9x^{4})(2xe_1+3x^{2}e_2)\frac{1e_2e_1}{6}$= $\frac{4x^{2}+9x^{4}}{6}(-2xe_2+3x^{2}e_1)$ 
So this is what I came up with. Can anyone tell me if this is right or not?